# Multiple insert in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to perform multiple insert in my sql server 2008 DB.

The insert looks like;

```
--pseudocode:

INSERT INTO DOCS (c1,c2) 
VALUES ('v1','v2'); 

SELECT @iddoc= scope_identity(); 

UPDATE table2 
SET y1='y1',y2='y2' 
WHERE iddoc=@iddoc;
```

This statement 50000 times.

I have a file batch (.sql) but I have problem with memory.

Comment: you want to insert the same values 50000 times or (i suspect) you want to insert different data? if so, where is the data you are inserting coming from? Your question is a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: Different data.
The batch .sql is the result of an elaborate csv file.
'v1','v2' .... 'y1','y2' are variables.

Comment: Really makes no sense to me. You add a row into DOCS with v1 and v2, then you save the scope_identity() which gives you the ID of an identity column in DOCS. Then, you use this ID to update a row of another table ... what makes you sure that table2 and DOCS share the same id?

Comment: >>table2 and DOCS share the same id

Yes. 
DOCS table store headers of a document. Table1 its "metadata".

However... the question is: I have a sequence like this:

Very complex sql statement with pseudodata (1,4,6);
Very complex sql statement with pseudodata (3,1,7);
Very complex sql statement with pseudodata (2,11,57);
Very complex sql statement with pseudodata (8,1,129);
 --etc

... The best way for accomplish this statement?

Comment: Traduco. alessalessio, ho visto dal tuo profilo che probabilmente comprendi l'italiano meglio di quanto io riesca a fare con l'inglese.
La tabella DOCS e la tabella table2 condividono il campo IDDoc. Per la tabella DOCS è una chiave primaria. L'inserimento in DOCS fissa la testata del documento e IDDoc, creato dopo l'inserimento, sarà utilizzato per creare record ed aggiornare riferimenti in un altro paio di tabelle. Quello che ho scritto è pseudocodice che semplifica all'osso quello che la query di inserimento reale fa.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, using GO statement

```
INSERT INTO DOCS (c1,c2) 
VALUES ('v1','v2'); 

SELECT @iddoc= scope_identity(); 

UPDATE table2 
SET y1='y1',y2='y2' 
WHERE iddoc=@iddoc;

GO 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to load a table (DOCS) with rows from a CSV file.
For that, the easiest way would be to write an SSIS package or use the import/export wizard to load the data quickly.

What I'm not clear about is what "table2" is used for. I'm guessing it is taking the same row data from the CSV but splits different columns into a seperate table.
Easiest way to do this, if the data volume is low (like it is now), load everything into one table and then execute a single insert.. select... statement to bulk copy part of the table columns into table 2.

Answer (score 0):

@treep - you can accomplish this task with a while loop.

```
DECLARE @a INT = 1

DECLARE @tmpId TABLE
(
    newid INT
)

WHILE(@a < 50000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DOCS (c1,c2)
    VALUES ('v1','v2'); 

    INSERT INTO @tmpId
    SELECT scope_identity(); 
    SET @a = @a + 1  
END

UPDATE T2
SET T2.y1='y1',T2.y2='y2' 
FROM table2 T2
INNER JOIN @tmpId TM ON TM.ID = T2.iddoc
```